# Utilizing an array within an inputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a little input box function where the user's input can only be months of the year (January, February, March etc), I figured it could be done via utilizing a variant variable (`months`). However, I am getting a type mismatch error , is what im trying to achieve achievable? thanks.

```
Sub test()

Dim NewName As Variant, Months As Variant
Months = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December")

Re_Enter_NewName:
NewName = InputBox("Please Write Month- Case Sensitive", "MONTH", vbOKCancel)

For Each Months In NewName ''Type Mismatch
If NewName = Months Then
Exit Sub

ElseIf NewName <> Months Then
 MsgBox "Please Enter a Month of the Year"
 GoTo Re_Enter_NewName:
Else
End If

Next Months

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use two functions:

One function to create the array with valid months - please check the code below: you have to use array not split. Alternatively you could read the valid month names from a worksheet or create the list automatically etc.

One generic function to check if a value is within an array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testGetMonthsName()

Dim MonthSelected As Variant, arrMonths As Variant
arrMonths = getMonthArray

Re_Enter_NewName:
MonthSelected = InputBox("Please Write Month- Case Sensitive", "MONTH")

If MonthSelected = vbNullString Then
    'cancel or empty
    Exit Sub

ElseIf isValueInArray(MonthSelected, arrMonths) Then
    'MonthSelected is valid
    Exit Sub
    
Else
    'MonthSelected is not valid
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Month of the Year"
    GoTo Re_Enter_NewName:
End If

End Sub


Private Function getMonthArray() As Variant
getMonthArray = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
End Function

Private Function isValueInArray(value As Variant, arrValues As Variant) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)
    If arrValues(i) = value Then
        isValueInArray = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Based on comment from @ChristanBuse - a more advanced version:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test_getMonthFromUser()

Dim strMonth As String, cancel As Boolean

Do
    strMonth = getMonthNameFromUser(cancel)
    If cancel = True Then Exit Sub
    
    If isMonthNameValid(strMonth) = False Then
        If MsgBox("Please enter a valid month name", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation) = vbCancel Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            strMonth = vbNullString
        End If
    End If
Loop Until LenB(strMonth) > 0

If LenB(strMonth) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Valid month selected: " & strMonth
End If

End Sub

Private Function getMonthNameFromUser(ByRef cancel As Boolean) As String

Dim strMonth As String
strMonth = InputBox("Please Write Month- Case Sensitive", "MONTH")

If StrPtr(strMonth) = 0 Then
    cancel = True
    Exit Function
End If

getMonthNameFromUser = strMonth

End Function


Private Function isMonthNameValid(strMonth As String) As Boolean
'will check according to systems language
'e.g. in German: Januar - in English: January
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 12
    If MonthName(i) = strMonth Then
        isMonthNameValid = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: I would add the Cancel check ```If StrPtr(MonthSelected)= 0 Then Exit Sub``` and leave the blank case as part of the re-enter logic. Better to use a ```Do... Loop Until...``` loop and remove the ```GoTo``` entirely. Cleaner. For the rest +1

Comment: Oh, and maybe use a Collection instead of an array of months then the ```isValueInArray``` would not be needed as you could check if the element exists by key

Comment: @CristianBuse: you are right - there is more to refactor (e.g. I would at least create the months-array/collection automatically)  - but I am not sure whether a collection or array is "better" - I think it's more an individual preference.

Comment: @CristianBuse added a second, refactored version

Answer (score 0):

You should also handle case when user cancels input box to prevent endless work

```
Sub test()
  Dim NewName As Variant, Months As Variant, mname, UserMonth
  UserMonth = ""
  'Months = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December")
  'Months is Variant/String array (1 element)
  'be sure to specify delimiter (comma)
  Months = Split( _
    "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", _
    ",")
    'Months is Variant/String array (12 elements)
Re_Enter_NewName:
  NewName = InputBox("Please Write Month- Case Sensitive", "MONTH", vbOKCancel)
  
  'For Each Months In NewName 'Type Mismatch: for each array in string
  For Each mname In Months
    If NewName = mname Then
      UserMonth = mname
    End If
  Next mname
  If UserMonth = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Month of the Year"
     GoTo Re_Enter_NewName:
  End If
End Sub
```